# Style "applike" header menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to make an "app like" header like this:

[image]

So there is an icon on the left side, followed by a logo and menu container and on the right side another icon.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BatML/2/)

This is my html code:

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="headerleft">
    left icon
  </div>    
  <div class="headercontainer">
    <div class="headerlogo">
      logo
    </div>
    <div class="headermenu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerright">
    right icon
  </div>    
</div>
```

This is my css code:

```
#header {
  width:100%;
  height:6%;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
}
  .headerleft {
  width:20%;
}
  .headercontainer {
  width:60%;
}
  .headerlogo {
  width:50%;
}
  .headermenu {
  width:50%;
}
  .headerright {
  width:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BatML/1/

there you have... and careful, you call classes in your fiddle with `#` insteed of `.`

It's all about:

```
float:left;
```

Comment: did you just add "float:left"? I have tried that before.. but thank you very much!